# Putting a focus on a iframe specifically in ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an iframe popping up for a payment portal on my website. When they get to this page I want the iframe to be in focus so they can just swipe their card like directed.

I have tried several different ways to focus on the iframe, but nothing seems to be working in ie.

```
$('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.focus();
$('iframe').focus();
$('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.document.body.focus();
```

`$('iframe').focus();` works fine in chrome and firefox, but not at all in ie.

Any ideas? Something I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried giving the iframe a `tabindex` too? Sometimes helps with `.focus()` for that element to get focus

Comment: @Pete I try not to work with iframes that often. I've not heard of a tabindex?

Comment: it's a general html attribute

Comment: @Pete I still hadn't heard of it before. I did look it up and try it, but it didn't work either.